# How can a plant become resistant to glufosinate?

Tags: botany, toxicology

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glufosinate), the mode of action of the non selective herbicide [Glufosinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glufosinate) is:

> Phosphinothricin is an [glutamine synthetase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamine_synthetase) [inhibitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_inhibitor) that binds to the [glutamate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamic_acid) site. Glufosinate-treated plants die due to a buildup of [ammonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia) and corresponding decrease in pH in the thylakoid lumen, leading to the uncoupling of [photophosphorylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photophosphorylation). The uncoupling of photophosphorylation causes the production of [reactive oxygen species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_oxygen_species), [lipid peroxidation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_peroxidation), and membrane destruction.

[image]

Now, in [this article](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=4338) from the University of California (Weed control, management, ecology, and minutia), it states:

> Researchers in Malaysia reported a few years ago on a population of goosegrass resistant to glufosinate in vegetable and orchard systems (Lee L J & Ngim J (2000). A first report of glyphosate-resistant goosegrass (Eleusine indica (L) Gaertn) in Malaysia. Pest Management Science, 56, 336-339).  For a number of years this was the only reported case of resistance to this herbicide.

What would have to happen in the weed for it to become resistant to this chemical/mode of action, and what would initiate this process?

Comment: Can you add real citations (Author, year, journal, volume, page) or links to the PubMed (or where ever this can be found)? Than we can have a look at the articles without having to find them first.

Comment: I think a general resistance strategy is to pump the offending molecule out of cells. I don't know if that applies here, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Chris still looking for those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phosphinothricin is a metabolite from the bacteria *Streptomyces viridochromogenes* which has a protein called phosphinothricin N-acetyltransferase (PAT). This Protein inactivates the phosphinothricin which is the reason why *S. viridochromogenes* is not dying from it. If you want a plant to be resistant to phosphinothricin you can add the gen for the PAT protein to the plant genom. 
This is also described in this paper about [herbicide-tolerant crobs](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16547651).

An explanation for the resistant goosegrass could be that somehow it got the gen for PAT, maybe by horizontal gen transfer from *S. viridochromogenes*.

In your case the publication which is cited in your [source](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=4338) contains another possibility. ["We hypothesize that reduced herbicide translocation is responsible for resistance to both glyphosate and glufosinate in these populations"](http://www.wssajournals.org/doi/full/10.1614/WS-D-11-00012.1)

Comment: Yes, this looks to be correct. Mind adding a reference or 2 before I accept?

Comment: I learned this in university this semester, but I'll try to find the publications :) 
There could be other explanations to your question